# Hadoop distcp temporary folder

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp

Does hadoop distcp creates tmporary folder on HDFS, when it copy from HDFS to Amazon S3a?

Do we need additional 1 Tb free space on HDFS, when we want to copy 1Tb data from HDFS into S3a?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found the answer and it really needs additional free space for temporary storage.